# Web font service

Tags: gratis, web-development, web-services, font

I'm looking for an alternative to [Adobe Typekit](https://typekit.com/) that provides fonts for web pages. I would like the service to meet the following requirements:

- Gratis
- Uses Open Source fonts
- Simple to use (I don't have to install anything on the server or host the fonts)
- Provides a simple script to add to a web page (e.g. Links to an external stylesheet for the font(s) itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I'm using Google Fonts and so far I'm very happy with it. Its has an extremely easy to use interface. When searching for fonts, you are able to set categories, thickness, slant, width, and more! When completing choosing the fonts, you can additionally set if you want the font in italics, bold, light, and more if available. It also gives you the options to select characters sets. When done, it gives a simple and short HTML code to insert into your website. It will then provide statistics on the impact on page load time.

## [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) (Free)

> Google Fonts makes it quick and easy for everyone to use web fonts,
>   including professional designers and developers. We believe that
>   everyone should be able to bring quality typography to their web pages
>   and applications.
>
> Our goal is to create a directory of web fonts for the world to use.
>   Our API service makes it easy to add Google Fonts to a website in
>   seconds. The service runs on Google's servers which are fast, reliable
>   and tested. Google provides this service free of charge.
>
> #### Open Source Fonts
>
> All of the fonts are Open Source. This means that you are free to
>   share your favorites with friends and colleagues. You can even
>   customize them for your own use, or collaborate with the original
>   designer to improve them. And you can use them in every way you want,
>   privately or commercially — in print, on your computer, or in your
>   websites.
>
> We are working with designers around the world to publish quality
>   typeface designs that are made for the web. If you are a type designer
>   and would like to discuss this, please get in touch.
>
> Many of Google's own web pages are already using Google Fonts, such as
>   Google's About page and Google's World Wonders Project which use Open
>   Sans.
>
> — The Google Fonts Team
>
> [image: Google Web Fonts UI]